# How to select a row named as SQL command via ActiveRecord's select method?

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using PostgreSQL and I'm not pretty sure about why is there no quoting for parameters that need to be selected with query. Here's the example - I have a field named "group" in my "motors" table. And now, if I try to

```
Motor.select("group")
```

The output will contain error:

```
  Motor Load (0.5ms)  SELECT group FROM "motors"
  PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
  LINE 1: SELECT group FROM "motors"
```

While the same commands for different fields named not conflicting with something like "group by" command works perfect.

Isn't there must be some wrapping quotes around or what? Or may be I missed something in config for that?

Help appreciated!

P.S.

I figured out that I actually can select row precisely for table, as:

```
Motor.select("motors.group")
```

But its not seems to me as good and clean..

Answer (score 1):

If you hand ActiveRecord a string:

```
Motor.select('group')
```

then it will use that string as-is. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to use things in a `select` call that AR didn't understand or AR would have to parse the string and attempt to figure out what you really meant; both of those approaches are highly problematic.

Unfortunately, if you hand `select` anything else, it will end up using simple `to_s` calls to convert the arguments to strings and then we're back to the first case so you can't say:

```
Motor.select(:group)
```

to get sensible SQL either. AR will automatically quote identifiers in some cases but not here.

The short term solution is to manually quote the offending identifier:

```
Motor.select('"group"')
```

The double quotes protect `group` from being interpreted as a keyword, they also preserve the case so you'll have to be careful about that. Double quoting is the standard way of quoting identifiers but MySQL uses backticks and other databases use other things.

The real solution is to avoid using key words as column or table names, rename your `group` column to something else so that you won't have this problem.

Comment: thanks, Motor.select('"group"') worked like a charm! But again, like and with Motor.select("motors.group") seem not clean). But will know for future thou.